# Can two classes access each other?

Tags: c++

If I have two classes called A and B,

*Note:* The following  doesn't compile.

```
class A
{
public:
   static void funcA() {}
   void call_funcB() { B::funcB(); } // call class B's function
};

class B
{
public:
   static void funcB() {}
   void call_funcA() { A::funcA(); } // call class A's function
};
```

**Errors:**

```
error C2653: 'B' : is not a class or namespace name
error C3861: 'funcB': identifier not found
```

Can you call the static functions of each class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
class A
{
public:
   static void funcA() {}
   void call_funcB() ;
};

class B
{
public:
   static void funcB() {}
   void call_funcA() { A::funcA(); } // call class A's function
};

   void A::call_funcB() { B::funcB(); } // call class B's function
```

This allows `A::call_funcB()` to see the `B` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the compiler a tip that the other class with be defined because it's a circular dependency.

```
class B;

class A { ... };

class A; // assuming separate file

class B { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make funcA and funcB Friend methods.