# Java Subclasses accessing each other

Tags: java, inheritance, stack-overflow

I have a basic class structure like this:

```
public class A {

}

public class B extends A {
    private C objC;

    public B() {
        this.objC = new C();
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    private B objB;

    public C() {
        this.objB = new B();
    }
}
```

I need `B` and `C` to know about each other so they can access each other's methods but obviously at runtime this creates a cyclic dependency and results in a `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null`. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100724/java-classes-reference-each-other) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827113/can-two-classes-access-each-other) but I can't seem to get a good resolution on what I should do in my case.

Is there a better way to approach this?

**Edit 1:** A more descriptive of my situation while keeping simplicity:

```
public class A {

}

public class B extends A {
    private C objC;

    public B() {
        this.objC = new C();
    }

    public String foo1() {
        int x = C.foo3();
        //do something
        return Integer.toString(int);
    }

    public int foo2() {
        // do something
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    private B objB;

    public C() {
        this.objB = new B();
    }

    public int foo3() {
        int y = B.foo2();
        //do something
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your particular scenario? I know you've gone to the effort of making a minimal example of the problem, but we might be able to suggest a different design if you could give us some context.

Comment: The fact that they're subclasses is irrelevant here - they could be entirely different classes and you'd still have the same problem.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, this is not the way to do it. Tell us what you need to do and there might be a simple way.

Comment: As it stands, the C ctor has no arguments and C.foo() has no arguments.  You might as well move the foo() method into B.  I'm sure your actual code isn't this simple, but we need more detail to really suggest structural changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Mediator pattern if you want to establish communication among different objects.

`Mediator` - defines the interface for communication between Colleague objects

`ConcreteMediator` - implements the `Mediator` interface and coordinates communication between Colleague objects. It is aware of all the Colleagues and their purpose with regards to inter communication.

`ConcreteColleague` - communicates with other Colleagues through its Mediator

Have a look at this link : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern